# How does Monaco achieve styling such as syntax highlighting?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, text-editor, monaco-editor

Is the following correct as a high level explanation of how [Monaco](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) achieves styling such as syntax highlighting?

The code editor is 1 large `<textarea>` element. This allows the user to input text. However, individual pieces of text in `<textarea>` elements cannot be styled separately, so instead the text is captured and used to create text elements which can be styled such as `<span>` and these elements are aligned and positioned to overlay the text in the `<textarea>` element, thus allowing for all the styling in the editor, such as syntax highlighting.

Comment: Yep, you got it.

Comment: @Ry- thanks I don't suppose you are one of the people who voted to close? This is my second attempt at this question, after the first one was closed and I don't know how to word it or frame it better and would really appreciate some some feedback.

Comment: Well, it’s a bit of a weird question in that it’s not clear why you wouldn’t be right. You looked into it and found out how it does it, yes? Where does the uncertainty come from to prompt the question? (No, I didn’t vote to close. Mod votes always close immediately.)

Comment: No it was just a guess at the approach, but yes I agree it is not the standard way to ask a question on SO. My last question was more open ended but got closed for not being focussed, so I figured giving a concrete example would make it more focussed so it doesn't get closed but that seems not to have worked! I think it is a valid and useful question for SO but I have no idea how to frame it without it getting closed!